vcpkg "error: while detecting compiler information"
I can not install vtk:x64-linux because of this message:
PS C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\VCPKG> ./vcpkg install vtk:x64-linux
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
  .....
  .....
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-linux...
Error: While detecting compiler information:
The log file content at "C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\VCPKG\buildtrees\detect_compiler\stdout-x64-linux.log" is:
-- Configuring x64-linux
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_required_process.cmake:127 (message):
    Command failed: C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/downloads/tools/ninja/1.10.2-windows/ninja.exe -v
    Working Directory: C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-linux-rel/vcpkg-parallel-configure
    Error code: 1
    See logs for more information:
      C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\VCPKG\buildtrees\detect_compiler\config-x64-linux-rel-CMakeCache.txt.log
      C:\Users\Juan\Desktop\VCPKG\buildtrees\detect_compiler\config-x64-linux-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  scripts/cmake/vcpkg_configure_cmake.cmake:314 (vcpkg_execute_required_process)
  scripts/detect_compiler/portfile.cmake:18 (vcpkg_configure_cmake)
  scripts/ports.cmake:192 (include)

Error: Vcpkg was unable to detect the active compiler's information. See above for the CMake failure output.

I am using WSL together with visual studio 2022 to compile my system for Linux x64 under Windows.
I installed the latest version of Cmake in my windows system and in my virtual Ubuntu system.
I send here the Logs attached:
# This is the CMakeCache file.
# For build in directory: c:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-linux-rel
# It was generated by CMake: C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/downloads/tools/cmake-3.29.2-windows/cmake-3.29.2-windows-i386/bin/cmake.exe
# You can edit this file to change values found and used by cmake.
# If you do not want to change any of the values, simply exit the editor.
# If you do want to change a value, simply edit, save, and exit the editor.
# The syntax for the file is as follows:
# KEY:TYPE=VALUE
# KEY is the name of a variable in the cache.
# TYPE is a hint to GUIs for the type of VALUE, DO NOT EDIT TYPE!.
# VALUE is the current value for the KEY.

########################
# EXTERNAL cache entries
########################

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:UNINITIALIZED=OFF

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_ADDR2LINE:FILEPATH=CMAKE_ADDR2LINE-NOTFOUND

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=CMAKE_AR-NOTFOUND

//Choose the type of build, options are: None Debug Release RelWithDebInfo
// MinSizeRel ...
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release

//C compiler
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND

//Flags used by the C compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=-fPIC

//Flags used by the C compiler during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the C compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the C compiler during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the C compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_DLLTOOL:FILEPATH=CMAKE_DLLTOOL-NOTFOUND

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_ERROR_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION:UNINITIALIZED=ON

//Flags used by the linker during all build types.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Enable/Disable output of compile commands during generation.
CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY:UNINITIALIZED=ON

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY:UNINITIALIZED=ON

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY:UNINITIALIZED=ON

//Value Computed by CMake.
CMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_REDIRECTS_DIR:STATIC=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-linux-rel/CMakeFiles/pkgRedirects

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR:STRING=bin

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR:STRING=lib

//Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories.
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/packages/detect_compiler_x64-linux

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS_SKIP:UNINITIALIZED=TRUE

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=CMAKE_LINKER-NOTFOUND

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:UNINITIALIZED=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/downloads/tools/ninja/1.10.2-windows/ninja.exe

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// all build types.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_NM:FILEPATH=CMAKE_NM-NOTFOUND

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_OBJCOPY:FILEPATH=CMAKE_OBJCOPY-NOTFOUND

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_OBJDUMP:FILEPATH=CMAKE_OBJDUMP-NOTFOUND

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION:STATIC=

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_HOMEPAGE_URL:STATIC=

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME:STATIC=detect_compiler

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_READELF:FILEPATH=CMAKE_READELF-NOTFOUND

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during all build types.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//If set, runtime paths are not added when installing shared libraries,
// but are added when building.
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//If set, runtime paths are not added when using shared libraries.
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during all build types.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_STRIP:FILEPATH=CMAKE_STRIP-NOTFOUND

CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME:STRING=Linux

CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR:STRING=x86_64

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_TAPI:FILEPATH=CMAKE_TAPI-NOTFOUND

//The CMake toolchain file
CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake

//If this value is on, makefiles will be generated without the
// .SILENT directive, and all commands will be echoed to the console
// during the make.  This is useful for debugging only. With Visual
// Studio IDE projects all commands are done without /nologo.
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON

//Automatically copy dependencies into the output directory for
// executables.
VCPKG_APPLOCAL_DEPS:BOOL=OFF

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:UNINITIALIZED=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/scripts/toolchains/linux.cmake

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE:UNINITIALIZED=dynamic

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_CXX_FLAGS:UNINITIALIZED=

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:UNINITIALIZED=

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:UNINITIALIZED=

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_C_FLAGS:UNINITIALIZED=

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:UNINITIALIZED=

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:UNINITIALIZED=

//The directory which contains the installed libraries for each
// triplet
VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR:PATH=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/installed

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS:UNINITIALIZED=

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:UNINITIALIZED=

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:UNINITIALIZED=

//The path to the vcpkg manifest directory.
VCPKG_MANIFEST_DIR:PATH=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/scripts/detect_compiler

//Install the dependencies listed in your manifest:
//\n    If this is off, you will have to manually install your dependencies.
//\n    See https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/docs/specifications/manifests.md
// for more info.
//\n
VCPKG_MANIFEST_INSTALL:BOOL=OFF

//Use manifest mode, as opposed to classic mode.
VCPKG_MANIFEST_MODE:BOOL=ON

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET:UNINITIALIZED=external

//Appends the vcpkg paths to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH
// and CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH so that vcpkg libraries/packages are
// found after toolchain/system libraries/packages.
VCPKG_PREFER_SYSTEM_LIBS:BOOL=OFF

//Enable the setup of CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH to vcpkg paths
VCPKG_SETUP_CMAKE_PROGRAM_PATH:BOOL=ON

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_SET_CHARSET_FLAG:UNINITIALIZED=ON

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
VCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE:UNINITIALIZED=x64

//Vcpkg target triplet (ex. x86-windows)
VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET:STRING=x64-linux

//Trace calls to find_package()
VCPKG_TRACE_FIND_PACKAGE:BOOL=OFF

//Enables messages from the VCPKG toolchain for debugging purposes.
VCPKG_VERBOSE:BOOL=OFF

//(experimental) Automatically copy dependencies into the install
// target directory for executables. Requires CMake 3.14.
X_VCPKG_APPLOCAL_DEPS_INSTALL:BOOL=OFF

//(experimental) Add USES_TERMINAL to VCPKG_APPLOCAL_DEPS to force
// serialization.
X_VCPKG_APPLOCAL_DEPS_SERIALIZED:BOOL=OFF

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
Z_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR:UNINITIALIZED=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG

//The directory which contains the installed libraries for each
// triplet
_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR:PATH=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/installed

//No help, variable specified on the command line.
_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR:UNINITIALIZED=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG

//Value Computed by CMake
detect_compiler_BINARY_DIR:STATIC=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-linux-rel

//Value Computed by CMake
detect_compiler_IS_TOP_LEVEL:STATIC=ON

//Value Computed by CMake
detect_compiler_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/scripts/detect_compiler


########################
# INTERNAL cache entries
########################

//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_ADDR2LINE
CMAKE_ADDR2LINE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_AR
CMAKE_AR-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//This is the directory where this CMakeCache.txt was created
CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR:INTERNAL=c:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-linux-rel
//Major version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MAJOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=3
//Minor version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MINOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=29
//Patch version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_PATCH_VERSION:INTERNAL=2
//Path to CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/downloads/tools/cmake-3.29.2-windows/cmake-3.29.2-windows-i386/bin/cmake.exe
//Path to cpack program executable.
CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/downloads/tools/cmake-3.29.2-windows/cmake-3.29.2-windows-i386/bin/cpack.exe
//Path to ctest program executable.
CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/downloads/tools/cmake-3.29.2-windows/cmake-3.29.2-windows-i386/bin/ctest.exe
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMAKE_C_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS
CMAKE_C_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_DLLTOOL
CMAKE_DLLTOOL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to cache edit program executable.
CMAKE_EDIT_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/downloads/tools/cmake-3.29.2-windows/cmake-3.29.2-windows-i386/bin/cmake-gui.exe
//Executable file format
CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_FORMAT:INTERNAL=Unknown
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS
CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Name of external makefile project generator.
CMAKE_EXTRA_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator.
CMAKE_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=Ninja
//Generator instance identifier.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_INSTANCE:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator platform.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator toolset.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET:INTERNAL=
//Source directory with the top level CMakeLists.txt file for this
// project
CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY:INTERNAL=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/scripts/detect_compiler
//Install .so files without execute permission.
CMAKE_INSTALL_SO_NO_EXE:INTERNAL=0
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_LINKER
CMAKE_LINKER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_NM
CMAKE_NM-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//number of local generators
CMAKE_NUMBER_OF_MAKEFILES:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_OBJCOPY
CMAKE_OBJCOPY-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_OBJDUMP
CMAKE_OBJDUMP-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Platform information initialized
CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_INITIALIZED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RANLIB
CMAKE_RANLIB-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//noop for ranlib
CMAKE_RANLIB:INTERNAL=:
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_READELF
CMAKE_READELF-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake installation.
CMAKE_ROOT:INTERNAL=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/downloads/tools/cmake-3.29.2-windows/cmake-3.29.2-windows-i386/share/cmake-3.29
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STRIP
CMAKE_STRIP-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_TAPI
CMAKE_TAPI-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE
CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: VCPKG_VERBOSE
VCPKG_VERBOSE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Making sure VCPKG_MANIFEST_MODE doesn't change
Z_VCPKG_CHECK_MANIFEST_MODE:INTERNAL=ON
//linker supports push/pop state
_CMAKE_LINKER_PUSHPOP_STATE_SUPPORTED:INTERNAL=FALSE

and
[1/1] "C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/downloads/tools/cmake-3.27.1-windows/cmake-3.27.1-windows-i386/bin/cmake.exe" -E chdir ".." "C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/downloads/tools/cmake-3.27.1-windows/cmake-3.27.1-windows-i386/bin/cmake.exe" "C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/scripts/detect_compiler" "-G" "Ninja" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/packages/detect_compiler_x64-windows" "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe" "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON" "-DVCPKG_CHAINLOAD_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/scripts/toolchains/windows.cmake" "-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-windows" "-DVCPKG_SET_CHARSET_FLAG=ON" "-DVCPKG_PLATFORM_TOOLSET=v143" "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_FIND_PACKAGE_NO_SYSTEM_PACKAGE_REGISTRY=ON" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_SYSTEM_RUNTIME_LIBS_SKIP=TRUE" "-DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON" "-DVCPKG_APPLOCAL_DEPS=OFF" "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" "-DCMAKE_ERROR_ON_ABSOLUTE_INSTALL_DESTINATION=ON" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_C_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_CRT_LINKAGE=dynamic" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS=" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE=" "-DVCPKG_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG=" "-DVCPKG_TARGET_ARCHITECTURE=x64" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR:STRING=lib" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR:STRING=bin" "-D_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG" "-DZ_VCPKG_ROOT_DIR=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG" "-D_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR=C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/installed" "-DVCPKG_MANIFEST_INSTALL=OFF"
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.34.31935.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.34.31935.0
#COMPILER_HASH#c51233d04c5939b077bae3db98b98a589cdbc7d7
#COMPILER_C_HASH#fee999f3e9c6edc63e065c1f53aeff44fde67df7
#COMPILER_C_VERSION#19.34.31935.0
#COMPILER_C_ID#MSVC
#COMPILER_CXX_HASH#fee999f3e9c6edc63e065c1f53aeff44fde67df7
#COMPILER_CXX_VERSION#19.34.31935.0
#COMPILER_CXX_ID#MSVC
-- Configuring done (2.4s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    BUILD_SHARED_LIBS
    CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR
    CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR
    _VCPKG_ROOT_DIR


-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Juan/Desktop/VCPKG/buildtrees/detect_compiler/x64-windows-rel

Several tools required by CMake are marked as -NOTFOUND, indicating that they were not found on the system. These include the C compiler, linker, archiver, and other related tools. This needs to be resolved for the build to succeed.
To fix the missing tools, I  need to install or properly configure the paths to these tools in my environment.
How do I do that?

Is the compiler installed? Install it and also maybe install binutils.

You're trying to build on Windows. You need to work exclusively on the WSL side of things.

Why do you want to compile VTK for Linux (WSL Ubuntu22 I guess?) using MSVC for windows?

@kiner_shah: I installed Cmake, g++, ninja-build, gcc, build-essential in wsl
in Windows I installed Cmake and executed the binary file of Ninja (does nothing)

@pptaszni: I supose that MSVC is Achronim for Visual Studio for Windows. Yes I am doing this. Is that incorrect? What should I do alternatively?

@molbdnilo: I am using vcpckg under windows command line to get the x64-linux packages on Visual Studio, yes. Is it not the correct way? How should I do it?

To cross-compile VTK for Linux using windows compiler might be doable, but I have no clue how to approach it. If you already have WSL installed, I would just go there and simply sudo apt install libvtk9-dev, then I would develop the rest of the project using VTK on that system.

You should use the Linux vcpkg (or preferably some other package manager) in your Linux shell. You can't use Visual Studio. (I think you might have misunderstood what WSL is and its relation to the Windows host.)
